# What is a continuous derivative for a complex function meaning? (from $R^2$ aspect)

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> If a continuous function $f$ on an open set $U$ is complex differentiable and $f'$ is continuous, then $f$ is holomorphic on $U$.

I'm confused about the statement mentioned that $f'$ is continuous. Looking $\Bbb C$ as $\Bbb R^2$, then $f:U\to \Bbb R^2=\Bbb C$ is differentiable if there is a linear transformation $d f_x$ from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^2$ satisfying $$f(x+h)=f(x)+df_xh+|h|r(h)$$, where $r(h)\to 0$ as $h\to 0$

Then $\forall x\in U$ there is a linear transformation $df_x$. How to say the derivative of a function is continuous? If I want to show that $f'$ is continuous on $U$, I should check $f'$ is continuous at each point in $U$.  It looks weird because it becomes $\lim_{x\to x_0}df_x=df_{x_0}$ and I don't what it means (take limit to a linear transformation).

Is my understanding about complex and multivariable calculus wrong, or in complex analysis I should look it as the case in $\Bbb R$( I mean change one real variable to one complex variable )

Comment: Think about the linear transformation as a matrix. A matrix function is continuous if and only if each of its entries is a continuous function (here, of two variables).

Comment: I know that linear transformation is continuous. Does it mean every derivative of a complex function is continuous?

Comment: By the way, I've read your book, it is really good for me to understand the concept of multivariable when I was studying advanced claculus.

Comment: Different notions. The linear map depends on the point; it varies continuously as a linear map as the point varies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your definition of a holomorphic function is wrong, complex differentiable is exactly holomorphic. If $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ is an open subset then $f$ is holomorphic if

\begin{equation*}
\forall z_0\in U,\;\underset{z\rightarrow z_0}{\lim} \dfrac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}\text{ exists}
\end{equation*}

The continuity of $f'$ is automatic, because being holomorphic is equivalent to being analytic and so being holomorphic implies that $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ and so being $\mathcal{C}^1$.

If you look at $f$ as a function from $U\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, then $f$ is differentiable and you have:

\begin{equation*}f(z)=f(z_0)+f'(z_0)(z-z_0)+o(z-z_0)\end{equation*}

So $f$ is differentiable and $df(z_0).h=f'(z_0)h$, for a differentiable function of $\mathbb{R}^2$, being $\mathcal{C}^1$ means that the map $df:(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mapsto df_{(x,y)}\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2)$ is continuous, \textit{ie} for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\|(x,y)-(x',y')\|<\delta$ implies that $|||df_{(x,y)}-df_{(x',y')}|||<\varepsilon$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm#Equivalent_definitions

Since $f'$ is continuous (because $f$ holomorphic) you have that $df$ is continuous and so $\mathcal{C}^1$ as a differentiable function of $(x,y)$.

You should also look at the Cauchy-Riemann conditions if you want more understanding between being differentiable and holomorphic.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations